# Need help understanding looping a program/ nested loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, selenium, nested, iteration

Working on a program to automate some daily functions that I do using Selenium to interact with a browser.

I have the script working exactly as I want it to with one email account, however I have several I would like to automate. I would like it to be able to choose one email, complete the entirety of the code, loop back to the beginning, and continue from the beginning, but with my next account in the variable.

For example, my login data is stored like this:

```
emails=('email1@email.com',
        'email2@email.com',
        'email3@email.com',
        )

myPassword=('passwordtext')
```

And is called during the login process in this way, just for reference:

```
for email in emails:
    emailid=driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    emailid.send_keys('email') # this is the variable that would need to change each time 

password=driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.click()
password.send_keys(myPassword)
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# then, several more work functions are completed using Selenium
```

Obviously, this doesn't work and leads to all of the email addresses in the variable being cycled through, and *then* the code continues. What I would like is for one email address to be selected, the rest of the program is executed, and then it loops back to the beginning and continues with the next email address in the variable.

I'm pretty sure the solution is a nested loop here and that this is a pretty basic question, but I can't get my head around how to set that up. Again, the rest of the program works perfectly, I'm just trying to figure out a way to loop through the program, changing *only* the login information, until the end of the variable. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why not put the rest of the code in the loop you have, Just indent it all by 4 spaces.

Comment: Wow, just gave that a shot and it did exactly what I was hoping. I had a feeling it was a simple solution like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you want to run *for each* email address needs to be indented under your `for email in emails:` line.
There is no need for a nested loop.

```
for email in emails:
    stuff_that_runs_once_per_email_address

stuff_that_runs_independent_of_email_address
```